# Simple schdule php script insert records twice while connecting to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks, race-condition, rds

This is the php implementation of the [same scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421094/simple-schdule-nodejs-script-insert-records-twice-while-connecting-to-remote-dat). I made this php implementation, because I thought I have issue with nodejs async nature. Unfortunately, they have the same issue. This may indicate that something wrong with my logic or mysql. I had hard time to figure why.

I have 10 commands stored in schedule table. When the day code, hour and minute are matching up with current day code, hour and minute. Those commands will copy into command table. This relies on the scheduler I am implementing.

[image]

Here is the result of after the schedule ran. It supposes that one schedule will have one insertion in command table. Currently, one schedule has 2 insertions in command table and schedule_id is NULL in the duplication. That is very strange. I spent a long time and couldn't figure out why. Is it a race condition? I don't get it.

[image]

Full code

```
<?php

include_once("./config.php");
include_once("./database.php");

function connect_db() {
    global $g_pdo;
    $g_pdo = Database::connect();
    $g_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

function close_db() {
    Database::disconnect();
}


function get_current_utc_time() {
    $date_utc = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    return $date_utc->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

function insert_into_pending_cmd($schedule_id, $device_name, $cmd) {
    global $g_pdo;
    global $g_is_test_table;    

    printf("\n** insert_into_pending_cmd **\n");

    $curr_time = get_current_utc_time();

    if($g_is_test_table) {
        $sql = "insert into cmd_test set CommandDate = ".  "'". $curr_time. "'".  ",". "RemoteName = ".  "'". $device_name. "'". ",". "CommandJSON = ". "'". $cmd. "'". ",". "CommandComplete = 0". ",".  "ScheduleId = ". "'". $schedule_id. "'";      
    }
    else {
        $sql = "insert into Command set CommandDate = ".  "'". $curr_time. "'".  ",". "RemoteName = ".  "'". $device_name. "'". ",". "CommandJSON = ". "'". $cmd. "'". ",". "CommandComplete = 0". ",".  "ScheduleId = ". "'". $schedule_id. "'";
    }
    printf("\nsql:, %s\n", $sql);

    $q = $g_pdo->query($sql);
  //$q->execute();
}


function is_schedule_already_pending($schedule_id, $device_name) {
    global $g_pdo;
    global $g_is_test_table;
    $condi = true;

    printf("\n** is_schedule_already_pending **\n");

    if($g_is_test_table) {
        $sql = "select count(*) as num from cmd_test where ScheduleId = ".  "'".  $schedule_id.  "'".  " and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = ". "'". $device_name. "'";    
    }
    else {
        $sql = "select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = ".  "'".  $schedule_id.  "'".  " and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = ". "'". $device_name. "'";
    }
    printf("\nsql:, %s\n", $sql);

    //$q = $g_pdo->prepare($sql);
    //$q->execute();
  $q = $g_pdo->query($sql);
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $num = $data["num"];


    //test
    print_r("print_r");
    print_r($data);

    if($num == 0) {
        printf("\nnot there, schedule not in cmd, %s\n", $num);
        $condi = false;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nin there, schedule in cmd, %s\n", $num);
        $condi = true;
    }

    return $condi;
}


function get_schedule_rows() {
    global $g_pdo;
    global $g_is_test_table;

    printf("\n---- start ----\n");

    // http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

    if($g_is_test_table) {
        $sql = "select ScheduleId, ScheduleRemoteName, ScheduleDaycode, ScheduleTime, ScheduleCommandJSON   from schedule_test order by ScheduleId asc";
    }
    else {
        $sql = "select ScheduleId, ScheduleRemoteName, ScheduleDaycode, ScheduleTime, ScheduleCommandJSON from Schedule order by ScheduleId asc";
    }
    //printf("\nsql:, %s\n", $sql);

    //$q = $g_pdo->prepare($sql);
    //$q->execute();    
  $q = $g_pdo->query($sql);

  while($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $schedule_id = $data["ScheduleId"];
        $device_name = $data["ScheduleRemoteName"];
        $schedule_day_code = $data["ScheduleDaycode"];
        $schedule_time = $data["ScheduleTime"];
        $cmd = $data["ScheduleCommandJSON"];

        // print schedule row
        printf("\n== start schedule row ==\n");
    printf("\n%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", $schedule_id, $device_name, $schedule_day_code, $schedule_time, $cmd);

        // schedule
        $arr = explode(":", $schedule_time);
        $schedule_h = $arr[0];
        $schedule_min = $arr[1];

        // print day_code, h and min
        printf("\n%s, %s, %s\n", $schedule_day_code, $schedule_h, $schedule_min);

        // curr
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655515/get-utc-time-in-php
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
        // http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
        $date_utc = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $curr_day_code = $date_utc->format("w");
        $curr_h = $date_utc->format("H");
        $curr_min = $date_utc->format("i");

        // print current utc day, etc
        printf("\n%s, %s, %s\n", $curr_day_code, $curr_h, $curr_min);

        // match day code
        if($curr_day_code == $schedule_day_code) {
            printf("\n..match up day code..\n");
            if($curr_h == $schedule_h) {
                printf("\n__match up hour__\n");
                if($curr_min == $schedule_min) {
                    printf("\n## match up d-h-m ##\n");

                    // is schedule already pending
                    if(is_schedule_already_pending($schedule_id, $device_name)) {
                        // no insert                
                    }
                    else {
                        // insert
                        insert_into_pending_cmd($schedule_id, $device_name, $cmd);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        printf("\n== end schedule row ==\n");
  }

    printf("\n---- end ----\n");
}



function main() {
    connect_db();

    while(true) {
        get_schedule_rows();
        sleep(5);
    }

    close_db();
}


// run
main();
```

output log

```
---- start ----

== start schedule row ==

254, BC1D300917, 2, 01:05:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

2, 01, 05

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

255, BC1D300917, 4, 01:05:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

4, 01, 05

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

256, BC1D300917, 2, 02:59:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

2, 02, 59

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

257, BC1D300917, 4, 02:59:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

4, 02, 59

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

258, BC1D300917, 2, 03:18:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

2, 03, 18

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

259, BC1D300917, 4, 03:18:00, {"command":{"description":"Up","channel":2},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

4, 03, 18

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

266, BC14100310, 3, 21:30:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"Down"},"type":"Becker1Channel"}

3, 21, 30

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

267, BC14100310, 6, 21:30:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"Down"},"type":"Becker1Channel"}

6, 21, 30

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

288, BC14100316, 3, 21:09:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"unrecognized command"},"type":"Becker1Channel"}

3, 21, 09

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

289, BC14100316, 6, 21:09:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"unrecognized command"},"type":"Becker1Channel"}

6, 21, 09

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

290, BC1D100603, 1, 11:30:00, {"command":{"channel":4,"description":"Down"},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

1, 11, 30

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

291, BC1D100603, 3, 11:30:00, {"command":{"channel":4,"description":"Down"},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

3, 11, 30

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

292, BC1D100603, 6, 11:30:00, {"command":{"channel":4,"description":"Down"},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

6, 11, 30

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

293, BC1D100603, 9, 22:15:00, {"command":{"channel":4,"description":"Up"},"type":"Somfy4Channel"}

9, 22, 15

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

298, BC14100399, 100, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

100, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

299, BC14100399, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

300, BC1U900046, 2, 03:26:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"Up"},"type":"Viva4Channel"}

2, 03, 26

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

301, BC1U900046, 4, 03:26:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"Up"},"type":"Viva4Channel"}

4, 03, 26

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

302, BC1U900046, 6, 03:26:00, {"command":{"channel":0,"description":"Up"},"type":"Viva4Channel"}

6, 03, 26

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

303, BC14100399, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

304, BC14100399, 2, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

2, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

305, BC1H600654, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "phoenix_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

306, BC1H600654, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "phoenix_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "DOWN"
  }
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

307, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

308, BC14100399, 5, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

5, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

309, BC1H600654, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "phoenix_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "DOWN"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

310, BC1H600654, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "phoenix_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

311, BC14100399, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

312, BC14100399, 1, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

1, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

313, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

314, BC14100399, 1, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

1, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

315, BC14100399, 5, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "DOWN"
  }
}

5, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

316, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

318, BC1M600204, 0, 08:20:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

0, 08, 20

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

319, BC1M600204, 0, 08:21:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

0, 08, 21

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

320, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

321, BC1U900046, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "tube_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

322, BC14100399, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

323, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

324, BC14100399, 2, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

2, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

325, BC1U900046, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "Viva4Channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

326, BC14100399, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

327, BC1F200700, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "Dynaveil_Multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

328, BC14100399, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "generic_blind_1_channel"
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

329, BC1F200716, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "Dynaveil_Multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

330, BC1U900046, 3, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "Viva4Channel",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

3, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

331, BC1D100603, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "somfy_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

332, BC1F200697, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "command" : {
    "description" : "UP",
    "channel" : "1"
  },
  "type" : "Dynaveil_Multi_remote"
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

333, BC1U900046, 4, 00:00:00, {
  "type" : "tube_multi_remote",
  "command" : {
    "channel" : "1",
    "description" : "UP"
  }
}

4, 00, 00

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

334, BC14100305, 1, 15:24:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"generic_blind_1_channel"}

1, 15, 24

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

335, BC14100305, 2, 15:24:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"generic_blind_1_channel"}

2, 15, 24

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

336, BC14100305, 3, 15:24:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"generic_blind_1_channel"}

3, 15, 24

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

337, BC14100305, 5, 15:24:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"generic_blind_1_channel"}

5, 15, 24

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

338, BC14100305, 9, 15:24:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"generic_blind_1_channel"}

9, 15, 24

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

341, BC1M600204, 9, 09:21:00, {"command":{"channel":3,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

9, 09, 21

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

382, BC1M600666, 6, 20:34:00, {"command":{"channel":5,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

6, 20, 34

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

383, BC1M600666, 5, 20:34:00, {"command":{"channel":5,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

5, 20, 34

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

384, BC1M600666, 9, 08:26:00, {"command":{"channel":5,"description":"Down"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

9, 08, 26

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

388, BC1M600666, 6, 20:27:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

6, 20, 27

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

389, BC1M600666, 5, 20:27:00, {"command":{"channel":1,"description":"Up"},"type":"motolux_multi_remote"}

5, 20, 27

0, 06, 25

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

592, MYTEST_3, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '592' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_3'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:20',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_3',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '592'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

593, MYTEST_1, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '593' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_1'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:20',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_1',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '593'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

594, MYTEST_2, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '594' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_2'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:20',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_2',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '594'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

595, MYTEST_0, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '595' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_0'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:20',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_0',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '595'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

596, MYTEST_4, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '596' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_4'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:20',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_4',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '596'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

597, MYTEST_8, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '597' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_8'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:21',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_8',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '597'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

598, MYTEST_6, 0, 06:25:00, CMD

0, 06, 25

0, 06, 25

..match up day code..

__match up hour__

## match up d-h-m ##

** is_schedule_already_pending **

sql:, select count(*) as num from Command where ScheduleId = '598' and CommandComplete = 0 and RemoteName = 'MYTEST_6'
print_rArray
(
    [num] => 0
)

not there, schedule not in cmd, 0

** insert_into_pending_cmd **

sql:, insert into Command set CommandDate = '2016-09-11 06:25:21',RemoteName = 'MYTEST_6',CommandJSON = 'CMD',CommandComplete = 0,ScheduleId = '598'

== end schedule row ==

== start schedule row ==

599, MYTEST_5, 0, 06:25:00, CMD
```

Comment: I'm curious about the use of prepared statements for the insert commands in `insert_into_pending_cmd` and `is_schedule_already_pending` or the select statements in `get_schedule_rows`  - as you are not using placeholders so you could simply do `$g_pdo->query($sql)` but when inserting data you miss the value of the prepared statements

Comment: I did what you said and updated the code above, still the same issue. If you search the MYTEST_0 in "output log", it only inserts into database once.

Comment: I've had a long look through this and tried to edit for my own eyes to make sense of what is going on - I think you could achieve this directly in the database by using an `event` - possibly in conjunction with a `stored procedure` if necessary. As this goes the page would need to be loaded by a user and left to run `ad-infinitum` whereas the `event` in mysql would run on the server once it has been kicked off initially.